# Creating all Bool binary trees of size n

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I'm trying to create all binary trees of size n, But can't think of a way to do it.

The Tree is defined like this

```
> data Tree :: * -> * where
>     Tip :: a -> Tree a
>     Bin :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
>     deriving (Eq,Show)
```

A size of a tree is the number of Tips and Bins it has.

I need to create a function that gets an `Int n` and returns a list of all the trees of that size.

```
> getTrees :: Int -> [Tree Bool]
```

For example for `getTrees 1` I should Get `[Tip True, Tip False]` since this is all the possible trees of size 1.

I can't think about a way to generate all the Trees of size n.

Comment: ok what have you tried? and what do you know about comprehensions or the `do` syntax for lists? ... **Hint** play with this: `let bits n = if n == 0 then [[]] else [ True:bs | bs <- bits (n-1) ] ++ [ False : bs | bs <- bits (n-1) ]`

Comment: If `n > 1` then the tree must be a `Bin`. If so, then its children must have size `n-1`. Since there are precisely two children, this is just finding all numbers `j, k > 1` such that `j + k = n-1`.

Comment: @Zeta doh ... indeed I only thought till 4 ;)

Comment: that was kind of my feeling too (indeed I just checked a few cases on my sample solution) ... but you know: Zeta is usually right ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the easy ones first: the trees of size one:

```
> getTrees :: Int -> [Tree Bool]
> genTrees 1 = [Tip True, Tip False]
```

Now, we have to think about greater `Int`s. So what about `2`? It turns out that there does not exist any tree of size two, if both `Bin` and `Tip` increase the size. Any `Bin` leads to an additional size of `1 + k + j`, where `k` and `j` must be valid tree sizes. One can see that this yields only trees of odd size.

We can therefore discard any invalid `Int`s before we continue:

```
> genTrees n | even n || n <= 0 = []
> genTrees n =
```

Now we know that our `n` is odd, and at least three. Therefore, we really have to use a `Bin` as a root for our other trees. Other trees? Well, remember the formula above? We need to generate two new trees with size `j` and `k` such that `1 + j + k = n`. Luckily, we have a function to generate those trees, called `genTrees`. We can combine all in a single list compre­hen­sion:

```
>   [Bin l r | i <- [1,3..n-1], l <- genTrees i, r <- genTrees (n - 1 - i)]
```

#### Exercises

- Prove that all used sizes in the list comprehension are valid, including the resulting tree size as well as the intermediate tree sizes.
- While the second paragraph provided some motivation, it didn't provide a complete proof that valid trees must have odd size. Prove that statement.
- Now count only `Tip` as size. What are now valid tree sizes?
- Rewrite the algorithm above in order to generate trees where only `Tip`s contribute to the size (after all, only they have a payload).

Comment: @EliBraginskiy: If you can restrict `a` to `Enum a`, sure. All that's necessary for `Enum a => Int -> [Tree a]` is another base case. However, you probably want to use `(Bounded a, Enum a) => Int -> [Tree a]`.

Comment: returning an `Enum a`  (where enum, is a function from (Int -> [a]) is exactly what I had in mind, can you point me in the direction of implement it like so? Without taking an `n` as a parameter?

Comment: `Bounded` + `Enum` makes this a lot easier: `getTrees 1 = map Tip [minBound..maxBound]`.

Comment: `Enum` gives you `succ` and `pred` (and `fromEnum` and `toEnum` and `[x..y]`), `Bounded` gives you `maxBound` and `minBound`, and after a finite amount of `succ`, `succ (succ (succ ... (succ minBound) ... ) )` should be `minBound`. This enables you to enumerate the whole range of some types, e.g. `Int` or `Bool`. It does not work for all types, though, e.g. `succ :: Double -> Double` won't enumerate the whole domain of `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

ok I guess some dislike the way I tried to lead to the solution so without further due: here is *one*:

```
getTrees :: Int -> [Tree Bool]
getTrees 1 = [Tip True, Tip False]
getTrees n = do
  leftSize <- [0..n-2]
  let rightSize = (n-1) - leftSize
  left <- getTrees leftSize
  right <- getTrees rightSize
  return $ Bin left right
```

#### note:

you can see here that you will get problems with even-sized trees because those will at some time get to `getTrees 0` which will pull `leftSize <- [0..(-2)]` and will end right there with an empty list

Comment: To be very pedantic, you only need `-XGADTSyntax`. The `Tree` type is not an actual GADT. Also, the original problem is substantially different - there aren't even any trees of even size with specification in the OP.

Comment: I commented on the second point - the first one should be pretty irrelevant IMO